# ember.js .find() only works when called 2nd time

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Main goal:** Using `.find()` to access a model other than the one available in the current controller -in order to compare data from the current controller's model with a piece of data from a 'foreign' controller's model.

**What triggers the comparison:**
I have a button inside a template with `{{ action "isResponse"}}`. This template's controller has an `isResponse : function() {...}`

**The problem I have:** The action is fired every time I click the button, but `App.Answer.find()` only returns content after the 2nd click. *I'm wondering if this is because the `Answer` model hasn't loaded, but am unsure how to properly set up an observer for `isLoaded` in my example (if that is even the issue)*

So how come App.Answer.find() returns empty the first time it's called??

```
App.ChoiceController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    chosen: false,

    isResponse: function() {

        // successfully returns what I want from this controller's model
        var questionId = this.get('question.id')

        // gets DS.RecordArray of the model i'd like to compare with
        var answers = App.Answer.find()

        // filter to get a result that matches this.get('question.id')
        var answer = answers.filter(function(ans) {

            // returns all entries that match
            if(ans.get('question.id') == questionId) { return true }

        }, 'answers.isLoaded'); // this observer doesn't seem to hurt or help

        // get the final value I need 
        var choice = answer.mapProperty('choice.id')

        // if choice array is not empty, (should only have 1 element anyways)
        if(!choice) {
            this.set('chosen', choice[0]);

        } else {

            this.set('chosen', false);
        }
    }

})
```

Here are the models involved. Both include DS.belongsTo attributes

```
App.Choice = DS.Model.extend({

    "question" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question')

})

App.Answer = DS.Model.extend({

    "question" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question')
    "choice" : DS.belongsTo('App.Choice')    

})

App.Question = DS.Model.extend({

})
```

**EDIT**

Here is jsfiddle showing the behavior. Make sure to open your browser console to notice that each button requires 2 clicks for action `isResponse` to function properly. http://jsfiddle.net/iceking1624/QMBwe/

Comment: please have a look at my updated answer, this might work for you now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comment I've retought a solution to your problem and one possible way might be that you can define a `AnswerController` of type `ArrayController` (since it's for a collection of answers) and then setup this controller in your `ApplicationRoute`'s `setupController` hook.

> Main goal: Using .find() to access a model other than the one available in the current controller -in order to compare data from the current controller's model with a piece of data from a 'foreign' controller's model.

Later on you can then require access to the `AnswerController`'s data using the `needs` API with `needs:['answers']` from inside whatever controller that needs access to the answers collection, and finally have access to the data with `this.get('controllers.answer')`. You can find [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) more info on the `needs` API.

See here a possible solution that works correctly, displaying the right choice already on the `1st` click:

```
App.AnswerController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('answer').set('content', App.Answer.find());
  }
});

App.ChoiceController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['answer'],
  chosen: false,
  isResponse: function() {

    var questionId = this.get('question.id');

    var answers = this.get('controllers.answer');

    var answer = answers.content.filter(function(ans) {
      if(ans.get('question.id') == questionId) { return true }
    }

    var choice = answer.mapProperty('choice.id');

    if(!choice) {
      this.set('chosen', choice[0]);
    } else {
      this.set('chosen', false);
    }
  }
});
```

And here a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/DCrHG/131/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for considering my question. As it turns out I wasn't able to get results with using .find().then(). Here is a fiddle with your proposed solution [jsfiddle.net/DCrHG/126](http://jsfiddle.net/DCrHG/126/). And here is a jsfiddle with the original code that exhibits the behavior of requiring the .find() to be called twice: [jsfiddle.net/DCrHG/125](http://jsfiddle.net/DCrHG/125/). *Make sure to have browser console open* Any thoughts or advice would be helpful! I think you're sol'n/reasoning is on the right track

Comment: The new solution works excellent in my code! It's clear and works well in my actual code. I can't thank you enough for helping me out on this one! cheers

Comment: I'd like to mention that I also had to add `controller.set('model', model);` in the Route where I used `setupController: this.controllerFor()`. Works perfect so far. Thanks again